# ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, geolocalización, windows-server-2012

Estoy usando [geopy](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/1.11.0/) en una aplicación `Python 3.6`y tengo que ejecutarla en una máquina anticuada que usa `Windows 2012 Server`. El problema surge cuando desde la aplicación se llama a esta librería ([geopy](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/1.11.0/)) en este servidor, ya que devuelve el siguiente error:

```
File "C:\ServAPI\Util.py", line 12, in getLocation
location = geolocator.geocode(name)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\osm.py", line 193, in geocode
self._call_geocoder(url, timeout=timeout), exactly_one
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\base.py", line 171, in _call_geocoder
raise GeocoderServiceError(message)
geopy.exc.GeocoderServiceError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748)
```

¿Álguien sabe cómo solucionar este error? 
Gracias

**UPDATE**

El código que da el error es el siguiente:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.exc import GeocoderTimedOut
# Dado el nombre de una ciudad, devuelve sus coordenadas
def getLocation(name):
    geolocator = Nominatim()
    try:
        location = geolocator.geocode(name, timeout=5)
        return location
    except GeocoderTimedOut as e:
        print("Error: geocode failed on input %s with message %s" % (e.msg))
```

Además, cuando lo ejecuto en mi máquina local (`Windows 10`), funciona sin problemas (ya, lo se, suena a "en local me funciona", pero es la verdad)

Comment: Con sólo ver el error no es posible saber la causa. Por favor, añade parte del código python que genera el error con el que comprobar qué pasa. Sobre todo necesitamos saber a qué servicio llamas y cómo. Asegúrate que este servicio acepte SSL, de lo contrario configura el parámetro `scheme` para `http`.

Comment: Hecho, he puesto el código que genera el error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posiblemente, en *win2012* esté anticuada la librería SSL. Prueba a indicarle explícitamente que el `scheme` sea `http`:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.exc import GeocoderTimedOut

# Dado el nombre de una ciudad, devuelve sus coordenadas
def getLocation(name):
    geolocator = Nominatim(scheme='http')
    try:
        location = geolocator.geocode(name, timeout=5)
        return location
    except GeocoderTimedOut as e:
        print("Error: geocode failed on input %s with message %s" % (e.msg))
```

Comment: Perfecto, ya no da ese error!! Gracias!! Por cierto, la pregunta tambien la he lanzado en SoF, por si quieres responderla allí también. Muchísimas gracias!